# Code on lower line number is taking priority over code on a higher line. Why?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I am trying to figure out why this code is taking a priority over subsequent code in the stylesheet.

```
/* Line 612 */
input[type='submit'], input[type='button'], button { 
    background-color: #d3dce0;
    border: 1px solid #787878;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    width: auto;
}
```

The following should change the border and background color right?

```
/* Line 764 */
.fakelink {
    border: 0px;
    color: blue;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Currently the border and background is still what line 612 describes. I want it to be what describes 764 has. Is there a way to override line 612 without changing it?

Comment: You're running into **specificity** issues. Here are two good articles: [**article 1**](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) and [**article 2**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**More specific selectors** will always take priority, regardless of weather they are above or below other rules for the same element. In your case, the *type* attribute is seen as a more specific selector than a *class*, therefore it gets priority.

Further reading here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

You can workaround this by using the same level of specificity on the rule you need to have priority. In your case, something like this should work:

```
input[type='submit'].fakelink{ ... }
```

Comment: Great - glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!important`:

```
.fakelink {
    border: 0px !important;
    color: blue !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Bad code. Want to use the natural way of ordering things.